# Is the DynamoDB table design efficient for Monitoring System?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have to design a DynamoDB table for a Monitoring System.

The attributes present for each item are:

- `name` (Monitor Name: String)
- `et` (milliseconds epoch: Number)
- `owner` (Owner of the monitor: String)

Below are the queries that I need to perform:

1. Retrieve all monitors: 
   1.1 That ran today 
   1.2 In `et` (*milliseconds epoch*) range
2. Retrieve by `owner` and `name`
3. Retrieve by `owner`
4. Retrieve by `owner`, `name`, and in `et` (*milliseconds epoch*) range

I came up with below selection of keys:

- Partition Key: Owner#MonitorName
- Sort Key: ET (*milliseconds epoch*)
- GSI Partition Key: ET (*milliseconds epoch*)

How I think queries would be executed:

- Query 1:

  - Query 1.1 `et = :val`
  - Query 1.2 `et between :val1 and :val2`
- Query 2: `Owner#MonitorName = :val`
- Query 3: `Owner#MonitorName begins_with(:val)`
- Query 4: `(Owner#MonitorName = :val) and (et between :val1 and :val2)`

Is this design efficient? What are the drawbacks for the design? How can it be improved?

Comment: Isn't 1.1 and 1.2 the same query? 1.1 = today = et range between (midnight) and now

Comment: @BertBlommers Yes, they are. But, added that to be as clear as possible.